# Unable to pull elgalu/selenium and dosel/zalenium images into my Kubernestes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, zalenium

I have set up a Kubernetes cluster.(not via Minikube) using our company cloud. Now I want to implement Zalenium by pulling the elgalu/selenium and dosel/zalenium images into my Kubernestes cluster.

Can you please let me know the exact command in order to do the same,since in the Zalenium portal, it is being shown only via Minikube.

OS: Windows 10
Zalenium Image Version(s): Latest
Docker version: 2.1.0.2

Comment: Does the command `kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 -it --rm --image elgalu/selenium podname` work for you?

Comment: How do you know that it is unable to do that? What errors do you get? What do the logs say?

Comment: Hi, now I have been able to successfully add the zalenium service to my Kubernetes cluster.....but now my question is how can I get the URL of the zalenium service deployed on Kubernetes, since when I was doing it via minikube, I was using the command  minikube service --namespace zalenium zalenium....can you suggest what will be the alternative command when I run it via Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: You should expose the zalenium deployment. Please read the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/). Because this is entirely different question, it should be asked in a separate post.